# need to generate css from scss file on windows 8.1 using gruntjs compass

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am working on a and facing problem to generate tabs.css file from the tabs.scss that is being provided . I have tried all possible options. I am able to successfully generate tabs.js under dist/ folder but failing to generate tabs.css.

I have run the following commands also:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev

npm install --save-dev grunt-sass

npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev

npm install grunt-contrib-cssmin --save-dev
```

But when I run `> grunt default`, I am getting the following Error.

```
Running "compass:tabs" (compass) task
Warning: Couldn't find the compass.bat binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am using windows 8.1.

I even tried to convert this tabs.scss to css using online converter http://sassmeister.com/. But here I am getting the following error :

```
file to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/box-sizing
```

Can any one help me in successfully generating tabs.css from tabs.scss file?

Comment: Then the path to `box-sizing` is probably incorrect, check it and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) for Windows. Sorry, I am not an expert in Windows, but [here is the tutorial](http://awordpress.net/blog/how-to-install-sass-with-compass-windows7-step-by-step-guide/) on how to do that.

Then make sure `compass.bat` is in your `$PATH`. After that it will compile with no error.

I have also tried to compile [tabs.scss](https://github.com/jasonfutch/enspire-ui-code-challenge/blob/master/src/components/tabs/tabs.scss) in sassmeiser.com, but it compiles for me with no error. So i have created a pastie for you: [pastie with css](http://pastebin.com/QPcYKMpB).